# Working with a java structure in clojure

Tags: java, oop, clojure, lisp

I have a java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList of [such things](http://home.dv8tion.net:8080/job/JDA/Promoted%20Build/javadoc/net/dv8tion/jda/entities/Guild.html):

```clj
(.getGuilds bot)
```

How do I iterate over it, call a method `getName` on each one and make another list of all the names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If i understand you correctly, the only thing you need to do is simply map over the list and get names. Since `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableList` is iterable, clojure will treat it as sequable collection. A simple example:

```clj
user> (import java.util.Collections)
java.util.Collections

user> (def files (Collections/unmodifiableList
                  [(java.io.File. "aaa") (java.io.File. "bbb")]))
#'user/files

user> (map #(.getName %) files)
("aaa" "bbb")
```

so, in your case it should be something like this:

```clj
(map #(.getName %) (.getGuilds bot))
```

Comment: You could also use `(memfn getName)` instead of `#(.getName %)`.

Comment: @SamEstep as far as I know memfn is a historical artefact and should not be used.

Comment: @nha Why do you think that?

Comment: Not the source where I found it but see the comment in this thread: http://objectcommando.com/blog/2010/05/17/easy-java-interop-with-clojure/ as well as Stu comment there: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-337

Comment: @nha Interesting, thanks! I did not know that `memfn` was deprecated.